# Read CSVfile and make alert when value changes

Tags: python, shell, csv

I want a script that scans a file that is being dumped by an rtl scanner.

When the dB level the number of line 1.0706257e+08 (>>> -25.18) drops to below a certain level 1.0709703e+08 (>>> -4.50518), I want to beep somehow.

Example of finding a high signal:

```
1.0706257e+08 -25.18 silence
1.0708473e+08 -25.18 silence
1.0708719e+08 -0.495787 <<< High Signal = beep
1.0708965e+08 -1.77369 <<< High Signal = beep
1.0709211e+08 -2.86055 <<< High Signal = beep
1.0709457e+08 -25.18 silence
1.0709703e+08 -25.18 silence
1.070995e+08 -25.18 silence
1.0710196e+08 -25.18 silence
```

The program outputs the dump as `output.dat` and the format is 1.0710196e+08 -25.18.

Comment: Please post any code that you've tried. Also what do you mean beep?

Answer (score 0):

The way to "beep" from a python script is:

```
print("\a")
```

This is equivalent to the old Cntl-G "beep" sound from early vt terminals.